# How to set a transition for when mouse leaves an element (hover off)?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've got multiple in the form of products which change their images on hover to another image. When hovering, the transition is smooth and takes 0.3 seconds with `ease-in-out`. When the mouse leaves the element, however, the transition is abrupt and it changes instantly. How can I make the transition work on mouse leave as well?

**CSS:**

```css
.my-reveal .hidden { 
   display: block !important; 
   visibility: visible !important;
}
.product:hover .reveal img { 
   opacity: 1; 
}
.my-reveal { 
   position: relative; 
}
.my-reveal .hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.my-reveal:hover .hidden { 
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;    
}
```

```html
<div class="my-reveal">
      <img src="" alt="skirt">
      <img src="" alt="skirt">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a class "shown" to your visible image and then add this piece of CSS:

```
.my-reveal .shown { 
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;    
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.my-reveal:hover .shown { 
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.3;    
}
```

This will allow your visible image to have a not-hover state with opacity 1 and a hover state with an ease-in-out smooth animation.

Answer (score 1):

With the current layout, all you need to do is transition opacity of the hidden element, and that will transition in and out.

```css
.my-reveal {
  position: relative;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.my-reveal:hover .hidden { 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-reveal">
  <img src="" alt="Bootiful Skirt">
  <img class="hidden" src="" alt="Bootiful Skirt">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `transition` to the `z-index` property. In the default state, set its delay to be equal to the duration of the `opacity` transition and, in the `:hover` state, reset that delay to `0`.

```css
div{
    position:relative; 
}
div>img:first-child{ 
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
div>img:last-child{ 
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    transition:opacity .3s ease-in-out,z-index 0s linear .3s;  
    z-index:1;
}
div:hover>img:last-child{ 
    opacity:1;    
    transition-delay:0s;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="" alt="skirt">
    <img src="" alt="skirt">
</div>
```